# python - list index out of range, working with CSV?

Tags: python, csv, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a CSV that looks something like this:

```
F02303521,"Smith,Andy",GHI,"Smith,Andy",GHI,,,
F04300621,"Parker,Helen",CERT,"Yu,Betty",IOUS,,,
```

I want to delete all the lines where the 2nd column equal the 4th column (ex. when `Smith,Andy = Smith,Andy`). I tried to do this in python by using `"` as the delimiter and splitting the columns into:

`F02303521,` `Smith,Andy` `,GHI,` `Smith,Andy` `,GHI,,,`

I tried this python code:

```
testCSV = 'test.csv'
deletionText = 'linestodelete.txt'
correct = 'correctone.csv'
i = 0
j = 0  #where i & j keep track of line number 

with open(deletionText,'w') as outfile: 
    with open(testCSV, 'r') as csv:  
        for line in csv:
            i = i + 1 #on the first line, i will equal 1. 
            PI = line.split('"')[1]
            investigator = line.split('"')[3]

        #if they equal each other, write that line number into the text file
        as to be deleted. 
        if PI == investigator:
            outfile.write(i)



#From the TXT, create a list of line numbers you do not want to include in output
with open(deletionText, 'r') as txt:
    lines_to_be_removed_list = []

    # for each line number in the TXT
    # remove the return character at the end of line
    # and add the line number to list domains-to-be-removed list
    for lineNum in txt:
        lineNum = lineNum.rstrip()
        lines_to_be_removed_list.append(lineNum)


with open(correct, 'w') as outfile:
    with open(deletionText, 'r') as csv:

        # for each line in csv
        # extract the line number
        for line in csv:
            j = j + 1 # so for the first line, the line number will be 1  


            # if csv line number is not in lines-to-be-removed list,
            # then write that to outfile
            if (j not in lines_to_be_removed_list):
                outfile.write(line)
```

but for this line:

```
PI = line.split('"')[1]
```

I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/sskadamb/PycharmProjects/vastDeleteLine/manipulation.py", line 11, in 
>       PI = line.split('"')[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

and I thought it would do `PI = Smith,Andy` `investigator = Smith,Andy`... why does that not happen?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It means there are fewer than two elements in that `list`. Put it in a `try` block, and have the matching `except` print out `line.split('"')`.

Comment: do you have a random empty line somewhere?  Also, why aren't you using the built-in csv module?

Comment: Why don't you use the very good `csv` module?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I don't have an empty line anywhere, I know that for sure. And I don't know, I could use the `csv`, I just really didn't look into it, because I didn't think I really needed to.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: "CSV," as a format, doesn't have a standard definition. The various implementations all have their own little quirks. The `csv` module can handle those quirks for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you think csv, think [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which is a great data analysis library for Python. Here's how to accomplish what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

fields = ['field{}'.format(i) for i in range(8)]
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None, names=fields)
df = df[df['field1'] != df['field3']]
print df
```

This prints:

```
      field0        field1 field2    field3 field4  field5  field6  field7
1  F04300621  Parker,Helen   CERT  Yu,Betty   IOUS     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: When I think CSV, I just think [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 probably because you haven't tried pandas :)

Comment: Oh, thanks! I've never used pandas before. I'll look more into this :)

Answer (score -2):

Try splitting on comma, not qoute.

x.split(",")

Comment: if I split on the comma,it'll split the name in half and thats not what I want though

Comment: As stated in the above comment, CSV isn't a simple comma-delimited format - the various implementations include extra rules to handle things like values that contain commas, as the OP's file does.